# CK editor select word

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I have to select a word in the ckedior content area. How is this possible?

For example imagine there are two question marks(??). This question mark by default wants to become selected. In that case we have a set of choices. The user will click on one choice and the question mark will be replaced with the choice.

How can we do this in ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the technical specifics, but I suggest you look here http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2012/02/smaller-selection-plugin-for-ckeditor.html.

I follow Alfonso Martínez de Lizarrondo blog he always seems to know what's up with ckeditor.

Hope that helps.